# How to take frequent values from an array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array of values lets say:

```
a =

   77.0000   83.3400  131.9300  131.9300  109.0600   37.6800   76.7100  189.3300 

  443.5000  328.1500  343.6400  343.6400  272.6000  421.8600  393.7900  353.8400
```

Now I want to get frequent values from 1st row of this array 
like this:

```
b = [131.9300 131.9300]
```

and all other values that are near 131.

Comment: Don't have matlab under the hand to try some filters. But try to take a look here http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/filter.html, hope it helps.

Comment: Clarify what do you mean "near 131". Do you have a distance threshold? Do you want the most frequent values or all values with frequency 2 and greater? What is the general task?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
>> [val count] = mode( a(1,:) )
val =
       131.93
count =
     2
```

Comment: but i dont want count ,i want to display the frequent values.

Comment: like this      131.9300 131.9300

Comment: maybe: `b = repmat(val,1,count)`